# Are "speaking for" and "If I speak for" interchangeable?

Tags: american-english, conditional-constructions, participle-clauses

> **Speaking for my experience in America**, the best way to handle it is …<blah blah blah>.

Is it a participle clause that can be changed into "**If I speak for my experience in America**, the best …<blah blah blah>."?

Comment: Yep, pretty much...

Comment: "speaking *of/about* my experience..."

Comment: I agree with user3169. *Speaking for my experience ...* is an odd phrase. It should be *Speaking of my experience ...*, which would mean something else (it may sound almost the same, but **[speaking of](http://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/american/speaking-of)** is a set phrase, and it has its own use).

Comment: It should be "Speaking _from_ my experience".

Answer (score 1):

To "speak for" means ["to speak on behalf of,"](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/speak+for) meaning to present a case for someone who can't present their case themselves. You're not trying to *speak on behalf* of your experience, you're trying to *talk about* it. If you are already talking about your experience, you would use the phrase "speaking of my experience" in the sense of "while I am talking about my experience, let me add this next point."

However, if you're trying to convey that your experience in America is subjective, and that you're not trying to make a general point about America using your experience, you could say something like: "Speaking (only) for myself, my experience in America taught me (whatever)."